# Html form submiting with background image

Tags: forms, submit

Html form submiting with background image

```
<input type="submit" name="fsubmit" value="Submit" class="Submit" /><br>

.Submit{
background:url(images/Submit-btn.png) left top no-repeat;<br>
border: medium none;<br>
clear: both;<br>
color: #FFFFFF;<br>
cursor: pointer;<br>
float: right;<br>
height: 65px;<br>
padding-bottom: 37px;<br>
width: 83px;<br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.icon_button{
    background:#FFFFFF url(http://www.limitedlink.com/images/png/ico.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
    height:auto;
}
```